# Html footer layout (ul and li in the same line)

Tags: html, layout, line, footer

Question: How to make it like ul and li in the same line. Can anyone help me with this problem. Thanks a lot.

```
Product product product product
Drink  Drink  Drink  Drink
Food  Food  Food  Food
```

CSS:

```
   #footer{
        display:inline;
    }

    #footer .footer_container{
        display:inline;
        border:1px solid red;
    }
```

HTML:

```
   <div id="footer">

         <div class="footer_container">

            <section>
                    <h1>Product</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Product</li>
                        <li>Product</li>
                        <li>Product</li>
                        <a href="google.com"><li>Product</li></a>
                    </ul>
              </section>

              <section>
                    <h1>Drinks</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Drinks</li>
                        <li>Drinks</li>
                        <li>Drinks</li>
                        <a href="google.com"><li>Product</li></a>
                    </ul>
              </section>

              <section>
                    <h1>Food</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Food</li>
                        <li>Food</li>
                        <li>Food</li>
                        <a href="google.com"><li>Product</li></a>
                    </ul>
              </section>
         <div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
ul, li{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

to your styles.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to remove the bullet points from your list using `list-style` in the CSS, and then set `display:inline-block` on the `li` elements, also within the CSS file.

```css
   #footer{
        display:inline;
    }

    #footer .footer_container{
        display:inline;
        border:1px solid red;
    }

    ul {
      list-style: none;
      }

    li {
      display: inline-block;
      }
```

```html
   <div id="footer">

         <div class="footer_container">

            <section>
                    <h1>Product</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Product</li>
                        <li>Product</li>
                        <li>Product</li>
                        <a href="google.com"><li>Product</li></a>
                    </ul>
              </section>

              <section>
                    <h1>Drinks</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Drinks</li>
                        <li>Drinks</li>
                        <li>Drinks</li>
                        <a href="google.com"><li>Product</li></a>
                    </ul>
              </section>

              <section>
                    <h1>Food</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Food</li>
                        <li>Food</li>
                        <li>Food</li>
                        <a href="google.com"><li>Product</li></a>
                    </ul>
              </section>
         <div>
     </div>
```